# Reposition the accordian arrow in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to nest one accordion control inside another and although this works as expect I'd like to customise it so that the nested accordion's arrows are indented relative to the top level.
This link shows how it is currently:-
[The bottom level arrows need to move in 20px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UYRP.png)

I can't figure out a way to set this in code or in scenebuilder. However if I open the running app in scenicview it seems to show it differently and I can see that the TitledPane is made up as: TitleRegion>StackPane arrowRegion>StackPane arrow. If I add fx-translateX 20.0 to this it does what I want.

Is there a good solution in code or fxml? Or can I get css to do what scenicview can do (I can't find an export from scenicview either).

I've just modified the Netbeans template JavaFX fxml project in scenebuilder. Using JAVA 1.8.0.92., nb8.0.2, latest sb +sv. My fxml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="accordianchildtitledpanearrrowcustom.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="79.0" layoutY="14.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="Example nested accordian" />
      <Accordion layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="320.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane alignment="CENTER" animated="false" text="Top Level 1">
               <content>
                  <Accordion>
                    <panes>
                      <TitledPane alignment="CENTER" animated="false" text="Bottom Level 1">
                           <content>
                              <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="example text 1" />
                           </content></TitledPane>
                      <TitledPane alignment="CENTER" animated="false" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Bottom Level 2">
                           <content>
                              <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="example text 2" />
                           </content></TitledPane>
                    </panes>
                  </Accordion>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane alignment="CENTER" animated="false" text="Top Level 2" />
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the applications css file you can add the following line to translate the arrow button:

```
.accordion .title > .arrow-button .arrow{
    -fx-translate-x: 20;
}
```

If you want to translate the arrow button of the nested `TitledPanes` only, you can use:

```
.titled-pane .accordion .title > .arrow-button .arrow{
    -fx-translate-x: 20;
}
```

The stylesheet can be added as follows:

```
 scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/yourPackage/yourStyleSheet.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Yes works a treat. Many Thanks. Any idea if there is a way to do this directly in fxml or code? ie. not css